# How to Render html in a chrome separate tab

Tags: javascript, html

In this example I would like to display the html generated in the `generate_html()` method in a separate tab.

Expected:
display a new tab that shows the rendered html a word matching game.

Actual:
I've created a method for render the html. My program processes a set of inputs that represent keys and descriptions for a word matching game. When the user clicks generate_html a textarea is created with the html to be generated. Then when the user clicks Render html the html from the textarea is rendered below.

```
function render_html(){
      // was html rendered?
      if(!htmlRendered){
        textarea  = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
        generated_html = textarea.value;
        maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
        rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("id","rendered_html");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        rendered_html.innerHTML +=  generated_html;
        rendered_html.innerHTML +='<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button> </span>';
        maincontentstyle.appendChild(rendered_html);
        htmlRendered = true;
      }
      update_draggy_boxes();
    }
```

The new tab should show the content from the variable `rendered_html`.

I'm looking for some way to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Passing data between tabs requires queries, ajax and a server response. AFAIK you can't do this with javascript.

Comment: You can use `window.open('')` to open an empty window, then set its HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the last few lines. `window.open('')` works.

```
function render_html(){
      // was html rendered?
      if(!htmlRendered){
        textarea  = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
        generated_html = textarea.value;
        console.log(generated_html);
        var new_window = window.open('');
        maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
        rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("id","rendered_html");
        rendered_html.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        rendered_html.innerHTML +=  generated_html;
        rendered_html.innerHTML +='<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button> </span>';
        maincontentstyle.appendChild(rendered_html);
        htmlRendered = true;
        header = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>Word Matching Exercise</title>\n\t\t<style>\n*:focus {outline: 2px solid blue; outline-offset: 2px;}\n\t\tdetails {padding:3px;}\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"boxes.css?v=9999\" />\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"event1.js?v=9999\">';
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89940905-27\">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n<script>\n\t window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n\t function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};\tgtag(\"js\", new Date());\tgtag(\"config\", \"UA-89940905-27\");\n'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="file:///D:/Sel.%20Topic%20in%20Csc/wordMatch/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>'
        header += '<script src="file:///D:/Sel.%20Topic%20in%20Csc/wordMatch/jquery-ui.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>'
        header += '<script src="file:///D:/Sel.%20Topic%20in%20Csc/wordMatch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>'
        header += '<script src="file:///D:/Sel.%20Topic%20in%20Csc/wordMatch/jquery.alerts.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>'
        header += '<link href="file:///D:/Sel.%20Topic%20in%20Csc/wordMatch/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">'
        header += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../logging.js\">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n</head>\n\t\t<body>';
        new_tab_html = header;
        new_tab_html += rendered_html.innerHTML;
        footer = '\n\t\t</body>\n</html>\n';
        footer += '<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///D:/Sel.%20Topic%20in%20Csc/wordMatch/GetElementPosition.3.js">'
        footer += '</'
        footer += 'script>'
        footer += '<script>audioOn = false; $(function() {$(\'.menulink\').click(function(){if (audioOn) {$("#bg").attr(\'src\',\"audioOff.png\");  audioOn = false;}else {$(\"#bg\").attr(\'src\',"audioOn.png");audioOn = true; speak(" ");}return false;});});'
        footer += '</'
        footer += 'script>'
        footer += '<img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;">'
        new_tab_html += footer;
        console.log(new_tab_html);
        new_window.document.write(new_tab_html);
      }
      update_jq_ui();
    }
```